# Como guardar cada linea de un string en una variable en c#

Tags: c#

es una pregunta sencilla, pero no se como resolverla, a ver si alguien puede echarme una mano, tengo una variable string multilinea que guarda los siguientes valores:

```
 string valores = 
 1,5
 2,00
 0,50
```

cada valor va acompañada de un salto de linea, queria saber como guardar cada una de las lineas de forma independiente en una variable cada una.

Un saludo.

Comment: Haz un `Split` por `\n` o `\r\n` dependiendo de cual sea el separador. Y en lugar de usar varias variables, deberas usar una colección.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partamos que en el ejemplo que proporcionas no defines ningun string multilinea ya que deberias usar el `@` y poner el contenido entre comillas.

```
 string valores = @"
                    1,5
                    2,00
                    0,50";
```

Si quieres obtener cada valor por separado podrias usar el `Split()`

[String.Split Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.5)

```
string[] partes = valores.Split(Environment.NewLine);

foreach(var valor in partes)
{
   decimal nro = 0;
   decimal.TryParse(valor, out nro);
}
```

Pero recomendaria que si quiere una lista de valores uses una lista

```
List<decimal> valores = new List<decimal>() { 1.5, 2.0, 0.5 };
```

creo que es mas practico que tener que parsear un string